# Absolute positioned div dynamically extending beyond relative parent div

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioned div inside a relative positioned div. Both of these live inside of a parent div I can't change, which has an explicitly set `width` of 150px. I want my absolute positioned div to be able to extend beyond this 150px width. I also need this to be dynamic - i.e. I don't want to have to explicitly set a width anywhere, I want the behavior you'd normally get by setting `max-width` and having the contents of the absolute positioned div fill the available space. Is this possible?

```css
.outerContainer {
  width:150px;/*can't be changed*/
}

.innerContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.absolutely {
  position: absolute;
}

.item {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <div class="absolutely"> <!-- want this to extend beyond outerContainer width so items wrap less-->
          <div class="item">
              first item
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              second item
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              third item
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              fourth item
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle version:
https://jsfiddle.net/3xbpzp7b/

Comment: `width: 200%;` for example to the absolute div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to add a fixed width to the `.innerContainer` element which functions as a kind of `max-width` for `.absolutely` as you describe it. If there's more content inside `.absolutely`, it will wrap, if there's less, it will become less wide.

```css
.outerContainer {
  width:150px;/*can't be changed*/
}

.innerContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}

.absolutely {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fb9;
}

.item {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <div class="absolutely"> <!-- want this to extend beyond outerContainer width so items wrap less-->
          <div class="item">
              first item
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              second item
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              third item
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              fourth item
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do actually want them to wrap at some point, just using a wider container than the 150px parent container. So ideally I'd like to be able to set max-width to 700px and have it only wrap at that point, but not have to set width to 700px and have it leave blank space because the full width isn't needed.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Please note that I changed my answer completely.